# Fixed point, errors and steep accuracies

Tags: numerical-methods

$f(x)=e^x-x-2=0$ on $[a,b] = [0,3]$

Fixed point iteration $g(x)= \ln(x+2)$ was derived from it with given $x_0=1.5$

how many iterations until $10^{-100}$ accuracy is reached?

I got $(1/2)^{n-1}*|0.247| =< 10^{-100}$

I can't handle this calculation as I get absurd numbers for some reason like 332 on my calculator. What do I do?

Comment: I can't tell if that inequality is right or not,  but surely $0.247\cdot 0.5^{n-1} < 10^{-100}$ when $n > 331.2$, so (at least) your calculator is right.

Comment: Well my $\lambda = 0.5$. What seems to be the problem?